# php system() command files due to '&' in password

Tags: php

I'm running the following command:

```
$cmd = escapeshellcmd( "echo '$password' | sudo -S mv \"$old\" \"$new\" " );
system( $cmd, $out );
```

This works when `$password` doesn't contain `&` but fails if it does.
How do I get this to allow `&` and any other special characters in the password ?

Thanks

Comment: That is such a bad idea in the first place... your webserver user is in the sudo group? really?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use `escapeshellcmd()` on the whole command, use `escapeshellarg()` on individual arguments.

```
$password_esc = escapeshellarg($password);
$cmd = "echo $password_esc | sudo -S mv '$old' '$new'";
system($cmd, $out);
```

You don't need quotes around `$password_esc` because `escapeshellarg()` adds them.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't seem to work.  Looking at the apache2 error log I can see: 
`sh: R6aAdf3C: command not found
[sudo] password for root:
sudo: no password was provided`  R6aAdf3C is the bit of the password after the `&`

Comment: I've tested my code and can't reproduce that error.

Comment: I've retested and I still get the same message.  For testing the password I'm using is `Qr450dwY&R6aAdf3C`  and the error logs returns the above output. If I remove the `&` it works.

Comment: I can only reproduce that if I have `echo '$password_esc'` instead of `echo $password_esc`. You don't need to put quotes around it, `escapeshellarg()` does that for you.

Comment: My commands are: `$password_esc = escapeshellarg($password);
$cmd = "echo $password_esc | sudo -S mv '$old' '$new'";`  so I'm not adding any extra quotes.

Comment: I don't know why it's different for you. I tested it and I don't get that error. The only error I get is that the password is wrong, since that's not my correct password. If I add the quotes I get the error you show.

Comment: retested this morning and spotted what was going wrong. The script does a `cp` before the `mv` I needed to `escapeshellarg` the password used for that as well. Thanks